Vyadha Gita in the original sanskrit text
Now i'm working on translating the Vyadha Gita (A Gita from Vana Parva in Mahabharat) in sanskrit text. I found the sanskrit one from All About Gita Website, and it was published by Belur Math. But there is some missing or incompleted sentences. So, I need help from anyone in Hinduism Stack Exchange. Is there anyone who can provide the completed one.
Thank you.

A incompleted shlokha is पतिव्रतानां नियतं धर्मं चावहितः श्रृणु ॥ २४ ॥

I have gotten both of these from Sanskrit Documents. This PDF of the VANA Parva is from the BORI Critical Edition. (Vana Parva)
The second is from the Kumbhaghonam Southern version which can be found here. (Vana Parva)
Original, sources: SanskritDocuments - Mahabharata
Both sources are good and authentic and should have the Vyadha Gita mentioned above.
